# Agora screen sharing in electron with react, Gives permission denied

Tags: reactjs, electron, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am building an electron-react app with Agora for calls. I am trying to implement the screen sharing feature.

As described in the following documentation I tried requesting screen sharing.
https://docs.agora.io/en/video/screensharing_web_ng?platform=Web#screen-sharing-on-electron

But I am getting the following error

```
AgoraRTCError PERMISSION_DENIED: NotAllowedError: Permission denied
```

I tried invoking the same function `AgoraRTC.createScreenVideoTrack` in react and electron but the result was the same.

How do I get permission to share the screen in electron with agora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found the electron way of doing it.

- First I request to share the screen.

```
const turnScreenSharingOn = async () => {
  const sources = await window.electron.media.getDesktopSources();
    setScreenSources(sources);
    setScreenSharePopupVisible(true);
  };
```

- `window.electron.media.getDesktopSources()` is a electron preload function that fetches the screen sources.

```
    getDesktopSources: async () =>
      await desktopCapturer
        .getSources({
          types: ['window', 'screen'],
        })
        .then((sources) =>
          sources.map((source) => ({
            id: source.id,
            name: source.name,
            appIconUrl: source?.appIcon?.toDataURL(),
            thumbnailUrl: source?.thumbnail
              ?.resize({ height: 160 })
              .toDataURL(),
          }))
        )
```

- Once I have the sources I show the popup from which I choose the source and pass the source id to the next function.

```
  const onScreenChoose = async (sourceId: string, cb?: () => void) => {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: false,
      video: {
        mandatory: {
          chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
          chromeMediaSourceId: sourceId,
        },
      } as MediaTrackConstraints,
    });
    const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    const screenTrack = AgoraRTC.createCustomVideoTrack({
      mediaStreamTrack: track,
    });
    window.agora.screenTrack?.setEnabled(false);
    window.agora.screenTrack = screenTrack;

    setScreenTrack(screenTrack);
    await screenShareClient.publish(screenTrack);
    setScreenSharePopupVisible(false);
    cb?.();
  };
```

Comment: I didn't understand the code which shows up the app in the Mac os security preferences for screen recording? How does it work?